# Plot k-NN Error : IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, knn

I'm new to machine learning and would like to plot a k-NN classifier graph.

I'm getting this error "*indexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1*" and I don't understand what the problem really is?

My data is really small for ML purposes but I'm only carrying out trails currently.
The data is structures in 4 columns.(image link is below the code) 1st is the index column , 2nd & 3rd are the two variables and 4th is the target classifier. There are only 21 samples.

```
import pandas as pd
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import neighbors
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report

n_neighbors = 5

# import some data to play with
Test_Cu_48hrs = pd.read_csv('Test_Cu_48hrs.csv' , index_col = 0)

# prepare data
X = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,1:2].values 
y = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,2].values
h = .02

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF','#AFAFAF','#FFFF00','#800080','#00CED1'])
cmap_bold  = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF','#AFAFAF','#FFFF00','#800080','#00CED1'])

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights='distance')
clf.fit(X, y)

# calculate min, max and limits
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# predict class using data and kNN classifier
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold)
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.title("7-Class classification (k = %i)" % (n_neighbors))
plt.show() 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0y3i.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to the way you're slicing pandas `df`. The way you do it you get `X` as one dimensional. Hence your error out of range index.

Try changing the lines:

```
X = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,1:2].values 
y = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,2].values
```

to:

```
X = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,0:2].values 
y = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,2].values
```

and you're fine to go.

**Proof**

```
# prepare data
X = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,0:2].values
y = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,2].values
h = .02

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF','#AFAFAF','#FFFF00','#800080','#00CED1'])
cmap_bold  = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF','#AFAFAF','#FFFF00','#800080','#00CED1'])

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights='distance')
clf.fit(X, y)

# calculate min, max and limits
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# predict class using data and kNN classifier
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold)
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.title("7-Class classification (k = %i)" % (n_neighbors))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick response. I understood what you meant , but after I changed the lines. It now gives me the error 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.

Comment: Can you tell me (1) the output of `print(Test_Cu_48hrs.shape)` and (2) which line produces the error?

Comment: The output is (21,3) and its line 18 which produces the error   '--->  y = Test_Cu_48hrs.iloc[:,3].values'

Comment: Ok that seemed to have gotten rid of that error , but now I get a memory error for line 34 ' ---> np.arange(y_min, y_max, h)). I checked the system resources and its consuming 80% of system memory. My laptop has 8GB of memory and i dont have anything else running. Looks like I'm out of luck. :(

Comment: You're getting meshgrid that is larger than available RAM. Try different values for `h`, like `.1, .5, 1.0 `  and see if you get rid off your error message and get picture of acceptable quality!